# How to have a transparent ion-footer ? - Ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm struggling to have a transparent footer to have a white gradient button.

I tried this one :

```
scroll-content {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

This work but the content is now not scrolable...

Comment: opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  ??

Comment: I did that earlier and this doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Yes adding below in the scss

```
.scroll-content {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
  }
```

along with

```
<ion-footer text-center no-border transparent>
```

in the HTLM will do :D

Answer (score 1):

I finally found !
To have a transparent header or footer you have to override the class "scroll content" in the ion-content and set the margin-top or margin-bottom to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work but as you said the content is no longer scrollable. The "transparent" tag should do the trick.

```
<ion-footer no-border transparent>
```

Sometimes I also have to do the following in CSS to force it to work nicely

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Good luck!